# How to extract values from a column and have it as float in pyspark?

Tags: list, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe that **visually looks** like the following. I want the column to hold float values only. Please note, currently the values have square bracket around it.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField 
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, IntegerType, ArrayType
data = [
("Smith","OH","[55.5]"),
("Anna","NY","[33.3]"),
("Williams","OH","[939.3]"),    
]
         
schema = StructType([
StructField('name', StringType(), True),
StructField('state', StringType(), True),
StructField('salary', StringType(), True)
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema= schema)
df.show(truncate=False)

Input:
+--------+-----+-------+
|name    |state|salary |
+--------+-----+-------+
|Smith   |OH   |[55.5] |
|Anna    |NY   |[33.3] |
|Williams|OH   |[939.3]|
+--------+-----+-------+
```

And the output should look like,

```
+--------+-----+------------------+
|name    |state|float_value_salary|
+--------+-----+------------------+
|Smith   |OH   |55.5              |
|Anna    |NY   |33.3              |
|Williams|OH   |939.3             |
+--------+-----+------------------+
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You can `trim` the square brackets and cast to float:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn('salary', F.expr("float(trim('[]', salary))"))

df2.show()
+--------+-----+------+
|    name|state|salary|
+--------+-----+------+
|   Smith|   OH|  55.5|
|    Anna|   NY|  33.3|
|Williams|   OH| 939.3|
+--------+-----+------+
```

Or you can use `from_json` to parse it as an array of float, and get the first array element:

```
df2 = df.withColumn('salary', F.from_json('salary', 'array<float>')[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.select(
    F.regexp_extract('salary', '([\d\.]+)', 1).cast('float').alias('salary')
).show()
```

Output:

```
+------+
|salary|
+------+
|  55.5|
|  33.3|
| 939.3|
+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to *parse the string* to *a float array* using a UDF and then you can *explode* the array to get the singular value within the array.

the program would be as follows :

```
import json

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType

def parse_value_from_string(x):
    res = json.loads(x)
    return res

parse_float_array = F.udf(parse_value_from_string, ArrayType(FloatType()))



df = df.withColumn('float_value_salary',F.explode(parse_float_array(F.col('salary'))))

df_output = df.select('name','state','float_value_salary')
```

The output dataframe would like the following result

```
+--------+-----+------------------+
|    name|state|float_value_salary|
+--------+-----+------------------+
|   Smith|   OH|              55.5|
|    Anna|   NY|              33.3|
|Williams|   OH|             939.3|
+--------+-----+------------------+
```